# how to align center div with block display?

Tags: css

how can i align center this blocks [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammad6006/c62PB/)?

a display is block because have width and height and now i can not align center of page this tags
html:

```
<div style="position:relative;top:30px;">
    <a href="#events" class="scroll submit">abcdefghijk</a> 
    <a href="#" class="submit">abcde</a> 
    <a href="#" class="submit">abc</a>
</div>
```

**Update:**
I thought , I should use `left:50%` for align center a div

css:

```
.submit {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: #CD1D27;
  border-radius: 9px / 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Francois One,sans-serif;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  width: 153px;
  display:block;
  float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `text-align` to your container:

```
<div style="position:relative;top:30px;text-align:center;display:block;">
    <a href="#events" class="scroll submit">abcdefghijk</a> 
    <a href="#" class="submit">abcde</a> 
    <a href="#" class="submit">abc</a>
</div>
```

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/c62PB/17/)

Comment: but i need display:block

Comment: @Mohammad What do you mean you want `display: block;`? You are using `div` which is a *block* level element by default

Comment: You can type it in there, it doesn't affect to the layout: http://jsfiddle.net/c62PB/17/

Comment: can you change a tag backgound to :height: 46px;  width: 153px; now?

Answer (score 0):

One more solution,

```
<div style="position:relative;top:30px; display: table;  margin: 0 auto;">
    <a href="#events" class="scroll submit">abcdefghijk</a> 
    <a href="#" class="submit">abcde</a> 
    <a href="#" class="submit">abc</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hey my friend use this

```
    .submit{
     position:absolute;
     width:300px;
     height:200px;
     z-index:15;
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
     background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;margin:auto;` to horizontally align the div provided you have a fixed width. if you want to vertically align the div at the center you need to set the height of the div as well.

For example

```
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;margin:1em auto 0 auto;width:340px">
        <a href="#events" class="scroll submit">abcdefghijk</a> 
    <a href="#" class="submit">abcde</a> 
   <a href="#" class="submit">abc</a>
</div>
```